# Error "version" is a required argument while building with rollup

Tags: runtime-error, required, args, rollupjs

I am using `rollup` to bundle my project.

At the start, everything was working fine, but I do not know what I changed in my config, I started getting this error on running `rollup -c`.

```
[!] Error: "version" is a required argument.
Error: "version" is a required argument.
    at Object.getArg (/home/programmersedge/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/lib/node_modules/rollup/dist/rollup.js:14625:11)
    at SourceMapConsumer$1.BasicSourceMapConsumer (/home/programmersedge/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/lib/node_modules/rollup/dist/rollup.js:15763:22)
    at new SourceMapConsumer$1 (/home/programmersedge/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/lib/node_modules/rollup/dist/rollup.js:15491:7)
    at Module.getOriginalLocation (/home/programmersedge/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/lib/node_modules/rollup/dist/rollup.js:16925:16)
    at Module.error (/home/programmersedge/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/lib/node_modules/rollup/dist/rollup.js:16942:26)
    at CallExpression.bindNode (/home/programmersedge/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/lib/node_modules/rollup/dist/rollup.js:12326:17)
    at CallExpression.bind (/home/programmersedge/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/lib/node_modules/rollup/dist/rollup.js:11415:8)
    at eachChild.child (/home/programmersedge/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/lib/node_modules/rollup/dist/rollup.js:11433:34)
    at keys.forEach.key (/home/programmersedge/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/lib/node_modules/rollup/dist/rollup.js:11450:5)
    at Array.forEach (native)
```

Here is my `rollup.config.js`

```
import resolve      from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve'
import babel        from 'rollup-plugin-babel'
import filesize     from 'rollup-plugin-filesize'
import typescript   from 'rollup-plugin-typescript2'
import commonjs     from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs'
import postcss      from 'rollup-plugin-postcss-modules'
import autoprefixer from 'autoprefixer'
import sass         from "node-sass"

const preprocessor = (content, id) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    sass.render({
        file: id,
        sourceMap: "string",
        sourceComments: true,
        sourceMapContents: true,
        outputStyle: "compressed"
    },(err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            return reject(err);
        }
        resolve({code: result.css.toString()});
    });
});

export default {
    input: 'src/index.ts',
    output: {
        file: 'lib/index.js',
        format: 'umd',
        globals: {
            ...
        },
        sourcemap: true,
    },
    external: [
        ...
    ],
    plugins: [ 
        resolve(),  
        postcss({
            preprocessor,
            plugins: [
                autoprefixer(),
            ],
            extensions: ['.scss'],
            writeDefinitions: true,
            postcssModulesOptions: {
                generateScopedName: '[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
            }
        }),
        typescript({
            tsconfigOverride: {
                compilerOptions: {
                    declaration: true,
                    moduleResolution: "node"
                }
            },
            rollupCommonJSResolveHack: true,
            abortOnError: false,
            typescript: require('typescript'),
        }),
        commonjs(),   
        babel({
            exclude: 'node_modules/**'
        }),
        filesize()
    ],
    watch: {
        include: 'src/**'
    }
  };
```

I am not able to figure out where the `version` argument should go in my setup 
or 
what's wrong with my setup. Can anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyways I fixed the issue.

Here the explanation for the issue

> The reported error is an error that occurs when trying to use a source
>   map when reporting another error. The actual error that occurs is
>   probably CANNOT_CALL_NAMESPACE, which from my understanding means that
>   you're trying to call a variable to which you bound * in an import.

and Here's the [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/rollup/rollup/issues/1817) you can refer to.

Comment: Can you please expand your answer to show how you fixed the issue? I hit the same thing and I have no idea where to turn off source maps because I am not using them to begin with.

Comment: @TomášHübelbauer sure... I suppose you are trying to a default import of some package... But has no default imports so you should try `import * as module from &amp;quot;package&amp;quot;`... To be precise... I had problem using the **classnames** package. To solve the issue, I had to do `import * as classnames from 'classnames'` instead of `import classnames from 'classnames'` if you still have any issues... Then reply.

Comment: Could you please try to see if you can use Rollup with [qrcode-generator](https://github.com/kazuhikoarase/qrcode-generator/blob/master/js/qrcode.d.ts)? InTypeScript I can say `import * as qrcode from 'qrcode-genrator'` no problem `import qrcode from 'qrcode-generator'` is not per the types, but with Rollup and rollup-plugin-typescript2 I was getting that issue with the `*` variant.

Comment: Unfortunately, I get *no default export* without `/js` and *cannot find module* with (in the NPM package there are no subfolder, just `qrcode.js` as expected).

Comment: I will file an issue so I don't derail this Q. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who encounters this, there is now a PR open with a fix:

https://github.com/rollup/rollup/pull/2012

Also, for many people once this is fixed, it will reveal the real issue: *Cannot call a namespace*.

I found a fix for that in [its own Rollup issue](https://github.com/rollup/rollup/issues/670) (happens with TypeScript):

```
import * as something_ from 'something';
const something: typeof something_ = something;
// Now you can use `soemthing` as usual
```

This only happens when using TypeScript through Rollup, not when running `tsc` directly.